# hdfs how to output size zero file in a specific directory path

Tags: file, hadoop, awk, hdfs

For example, I want to output all zero files path in a specific directory like `hdfs://<DIRECTORY>`.

```
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03767.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup      71667 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03768.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup      94330 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03769.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup      14756 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03770.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03771.pb.zstd
```

```
// output
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03767.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03771.pb.zstd
```

I want to use `hdfs -ls` or `hdfs -du` and `awk`, but I am not familiar with `awk`.
How to implement it.
Thanks in advances.

Comment: What is the output of `hdfs -du` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output of `hdfs ls` is *reliable* :

```
$ hdfs ls | awk '$5 == 0'
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03767.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/part-03771.pb.zstd
```

This is one of the most simple `awk` command ;)

Comment: I have updated question, if I want to recursively output file path which size is zero in specific directory `hdfs://<DIRECTORY>`. How to implement it with `awk`? Thanks in advances.

Comment: If you have a new question, open a new one