# hdfs how to recursively output size zero file in a specific directory path

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

for example, I want to recursively output file path which size is zero in recursive timestamp directory like follows `hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/<TIMESTAMP>`

```
// <DIRECTORY>/<TIMESTAMP1>
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/20221015/part-03767.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup      71667 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/20221015/part-03768.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup      94330 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/20221015/part-03769.pb.zstd

// <DIRECTORY>/<TIMESTAMP2>
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup      14756 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/20221016/part-03770.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/20221016/part-03771.pb.zstd
```

`<TIMESTAMP>` is from `20220501` to `20221231`

```
// output
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/20221015/part-03767.pb.zstd
-rw-r--r--   3 USER supergroup          0 2022-10-23 21:52 hdfs://<DIRECTORY>/20221016/part-03771.pb.zstd
```

Thanks in advances.

Comment: @Mofi Sorry for adding a wrong tag and have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

To get files recursively,

```
hadoop fs -ls -R
```

Combine this with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927341/hdfs-how-to-output-size-zero-file-in-a-specific-directory-path)